# SQL Server full text search too slow

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, performance

I'm running into issues with SQL Server's full-text search running too slow.

It's taking over a minute to run a full-text search and JOIN query (see below)

```
select * from

(SELECT 
    (row_number() over ( order by b.BookKey)) as RowNumber,
    p.PublishCity,
    b.BookKey,
    b.BookTitle
from
    Books b (nolock)
    inner join PublishedRegions p (nolock)
        on b.BookKey = p.BookKey
where
    contains(p.PublishCity, 'France') or
    contains(b.BookTitle, 'France')
) as t1

where
    RowNumber between 200 and 210
```

- For reference, there are about 500k rows in the Books table and PublishedRegions table
- I couldn't put PublishedCity in the Books table, because SQL Server only lets you define one full-text index per table.
- Note: The last part RowNumber between 200 and 210 is was just inserted arbitrarily. I could have chosen any set of rows and the results still take long
- Books table has a full-text index on BookName NVARCHAR(255)
- PublishedRegions has a full text index on PublishedCity NVARCHAR(255).

Any ideas how to improve the performance of this?

Thanks!

Comment: which version of Sql Server you are using

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then for `paging` instead of using `Row_Number` use `OFFSET..FETCH`. Something like this.

```
SELECT
    p.PublishCity,
    b.BookKey,
    b.BookTitle
FROM
    Books b (nolock)
    INNER JOIN PublishedRegions p (nolock)
        ON b.BookKey = p.BookKey
WHERE
    CONTAINS(p.PublishCity, 'France') OR
    CONTAINS(b.BookTitle, 'France')
ORDER BY b.BookKey OFFSET 199 ROWS FETCH NEXT 11 ROWS ONLY
```

`Offset-Fetch` approach will have better performance than `Row_number`. [*Check here*](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/) for detailed comparison